# How to make boost unordered_map to support flyweight<string>

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, flyweight-pattern

I am trying to do the following:

```
boost::unordered_map<boost::flyweight<std::string>, boost::flyweight<std::string> > map;

        boost::flyweight<std::string> foo(name);
        map[foo] = foo;
```

But the compiler complains:
"error C2665: 'boost::hash_value' : none of the 17 overloads could convert all the argument types".

But I have defined the following function:

```
std::size_t hash_value(const boost::flyweight<std::string> & b)
{
    boost::hash<std::string> hasher;
    const std::string & str = b.get();
    return hasher(str);
}
bool operator==(const boost::flyweight<std::string>& f, const boost::flyweight<std::string> & second)
{
    return f.get() == second.get();
}
```

But it doesn´t compile.

What do I need to do to make boost unordered_map to support flyweight?

[EDIT]
I got it to work with the following code:

```
    struct flyweight_hash
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const boost::flyweight<std::string> &elm) const
        {
            boost::hash<std::string> hasher;
            const std::string & str = elm.get();
            return hasher(str);
        }
    };
```

and passed it as a template parameter to the construction of the map:

```
boost::unordered_map<boost::flyweight<std::string>, boost::flyweight<std::string> , flyweight_hash > map;
```

In this case I don´t understand way overloading hash_value didn´t worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::hash` calls `hash_value` through argument dependent lookup (ADL). You are trying to define a `hash_value` function for a class in namespace `boost`. Hence your `hash_value` function would need to go into this namespace as well for ADL to work. Unfortunately, adding functions to a foreign namespace is rather evil and should be avoided. Your solution of using a custom hasher seems fine.

A little example code to illustrate:

```
namespace boost {
  // somewhere in boost
  template<typename T>
  std::size_t hash(const T& t) { 
    // call using ADL
    // e.g. if called with object of class type foo::bar this will
    // pick up foo::hash_value despite the lack of namespace
    // qualification
    return hash_value(t); 
  }
}

// your hash_value (presumably in the global namespace)
// not picked up by above call
std::size_t hash_value(boost::flyweight<T>...);

namespace boost {
  // this would be picked up but is slightly evil
  std::size_t hash_value(boost::flyweight<T>...);
}
```

Comment: It's only bad because `boost::unordered_map`'s default hasher doesn't seem to trigger ADL by `using boost::hash_value; return hash_value(key);`. I can't check that right now though.

Comment: @Xeo The default hasher should be `boost::hash` and should not be specific to `unordered_map`. At least the doc says so.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't change that ADL-enabled calls don't seem to be used.

Comment: @Xeo How would ADL be able to find the `hash_value` shown in the example? `flyweight` is in namespace `boost` and there is no matching overload in that namespace and the one outside of the namespace won't be considered. Unless OP actually defined his `hash_value` in that namespace, but I doubt that.

Comment: Err, right.. nevermind me, I actually got a bit confused here. :|

Comment: @Xeo I added some example code to make things a little clearer.

Answer (score 7):

It is a pity to hash something which has already been hashed.  Flyweight keeps a single instance of equal objects, so it is more efficient to hash the address of this instance, instead of its content.  I do as follows (in `std`, not in `boost`, as I'm using C++11, so I'm extending `std::hash`, not `boost::hash`):

```
namespace std
{
  template <typename T>
  struct hash<boost::flyweight<T, boost::flyweights::no_tracking>>
  {
    using value_type = boost::flyweight<T, boost::flyweights::no_tracking>;
    size_t operator()(const value_type& ss) const
    {
      hash<const void*> hasher;
      return hasher(&ss.get());
    }
  };
}
```

I have been confirmed that this works by design, not by accident: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2013/03/78007.php